# Is it possible to fire an event from a LWC and handle in another LWC which is not in containment hierarchy?

Tags: lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components, lightning-events

Is it possible to fire an event from a lightning web component and handle in another lightning web component which is not in containment hierarchy? This is achievable in Aura component using application event.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. It can be achieved using the *pub-sub* model.

> To communicate between components that aren’t in the same DOM tree, use a singleton library that follows the publish-subscribe pattern.

Refer to [Communicate Between Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.events_pubsub) documentation for more details.

> For example, if you add two components to a Lightning page in Lightning App Builder, use the `pubsub` module to send events between them.

You can find the `pubsub` module [here on lwc-recipe](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/pubsub)

Comment: Thank you very much Jayant for your help. I was not aware of publish/subscribe modal but now I used this and it worked for me.